# Clone product model/object in Magento

Tags: php, magento, clone, product

Is it possible to clone a product model/object instance in Magento? Basically I'm hooking in to the save event of a product and wish to automatically create a child product based of the main product. The information will be largely the same, except for SKU's and an attribute. I've tried this:

```
$product = clone $parent_product;
$product->setName('I am testing');
$product->save();
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to look at `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product->duplicate()`